# Bash: Having 2 files, how do I check if a certain name in the first one also appears in the second

Tags: shell-script

Ok so, the problem is a little more complex than that

I have 2 files, let's say *file1* and *file2*, each with the following data:

```
name of the game, hours spent playing it, last 7 days
```

file1:

```
game1 100 20
game3 40   5
```

file2:

```
game1 90  25
game4 40   2
```

Objectives:

- if a game is in both files, subtract the hours spent playing of *file1 - file2*
- If a game is only in *file1*, show it, but as the original *(file1 - 0)*
- If a game is only in *file2*, show it, but as the negative of the original *(0 - file2)*

How can I do this in `bash`?

Comment: *in* bash, or from the (bash) command-line, using unix file processing tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-the-cuff answer, assuming the files are sorted:

```
awk '{$2= -$2; $3= -$3} 1' file2 |
  join -a1 -a2 file1 - |
  awk 'NF > 3 {$2+=$4; $3+=$5; NF=3} 1'
```

Output on provided input:

```
game1 10 -5
game3 40 5
game4 -40 -2
```

(If the files aren't sorted, just sort them and keep them sorted.  It will make things easier.)

---

Note that this uses only [POSIX features of `join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) and [POSIX features of Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), so it will work nearly anywhere.

---

`$2` in Awk is a reference to the second field.  `$3` is a reference to the third field (of each line of the file processed).  `1` appearing outside braces `{...}` just means "true," so the default action of printing the line is performed.

Essentially the first Awk command just makes the numbers in `file2` into negative numbers.

The `join` command joins `file1` to the text provided on its standard input (what it receives from Awk).  The `-` after `file1` in the `join` command (rather than another file name) means "use standard input."  The options `-a1` and `-a2` mean that any unpairable lines in either the first or second file are output as-is.

The final Awk command takes the lines that have been paired, i.e. lines where the **N**umber of **F**ields is greater than 3 (`NF > 3`), and adds their fourth field to their second field, adds their fifth field to their third field, and then truncates the fourth and fifth fields.

Again, the final `1` outside braces is used to trigger Awk's default action, "print."

(See [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) for more and to learn Awk properly.)

---

There is a lot going on here.  I recommend running each part of these commands before adding the next part.   First:

```
awk '{$2= -$2; $3= -$3} 1' file2
```

and study and understand that.  Then:

```
awk '{$2= -$2; $3= -$3} 1' file2 |
  join -a1 -a2 file1 -
```

And study and understand that.  (Also try leaving out the `-a1` and `-a2` flags, or leaving out just one of them.)

Then use the full command:

```
awk '{$2= -$2; $3= -$3} 1' file2 |
  join -a1 -a2 file1 - |
  awk 'NF > 3 {$2+=$4; $3+=$5; NF=3} 1'
```

And see if it makes more sense.

Comment: That is indeed the desired output!  I'm trying to understand how and why it works before testing it but if you could give me a small insight I would really appreciate it as I'm still a newbie to bash sintax

Comment: @Fosh, I added a hurried explanation.  Hope it helps.  I've written extensively on this site about text processing, occasionally with much longer explanations, so you may want to browse my other answers.  If you want to learn Awk *properly,* I highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Answer (score 0):

Inelegant `bash`, `join`, and *GNU* `sed` variant:

```
join -a1 -a2 -o 0 1.2,2.2,1.3,2.3 file1 <(sed 's/ \([0-9]*\)/ -\1/g' file2) | \
sed 's/ -/-/g;s/[0-9]*-[0-9]*/$((&))/g;s/.*/echo &/eg'
```

Output:

```
game1 10 -5
game3 40 5
game4 -40 -2
```